# Ninja forms + Handsontable, add new table row with button?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, handsontable, ninja-forms

I'm using the Ninja forms plugin on a WordPress site which has a table addon. The table addon is using version 0.16.1 of Handsontable to create the data tables.

I'm trying to add a custom button which will allow the user to add a new row in the table in click, in addition to pressing enter inside a row two times.

I tried to use a varation of a script I found in this JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EfhqJ/52/ but it doesn't do anything and I get no script errors.

```
$('#addbottom').on('click', function () {
 $edit.handsontable('alter', 'insert_row');
});
```

If Ninja forms have implemented Handsontable with their plugin addon correctly, is this the function I should be using to add a new row? Or is there another/a better way I should try?